# Restrict access to iphone till a random reset code is provided. reset code is communicated between application and user via email

Tags: ios

I am making an customized alarm clock  iPhone app. In order to turn the alarm clock off, the user has to type in a random code that is sent to his email before 2 hours before the alarm. I am looking for a mechanism by which I can restrict complete access till the user puts in the random reset code. Also, at this time, the user should not be allowed to reduce the volume, turn off the phone, or any other mechanisms.

Comment: I can't see this being a big seller.

Comment: Sounds more like malware than an app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Also, at this time, the user should not be allowed to reduce the volume, turn off the phone, or any other mechanisms.`

There aren't any public APIs that let you do these. It's actually against app guidelines to try, and it will get your app rejected.

You can, however, control what features / access the user has to information within your app. In example, you might create a "locked" screen, which requires a user to enter a code received via email before he can use/resume the app.

Answer (score 1):

Read the app store guidelines, virtually everything above is not only not possible, but even if you were able to do one or two of them, your app would certainly be rejected from the App Store (I'm assuming that is what you would be doing with it).  Apps aren't permitted to alter what user controls and buttons on the device do.